# How to print two list simultaneously?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my views.py file in django

```html
def twitter_trend(request):
    tweets, urls = main()
    context = {
        "tweets": tweets,
        "urls": urls,
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, "feed/trends.html", context)
```

In my template I want to print the value of trends and urls simultaneously.

This is my template file

```html
{% extends 'feed/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="thumbnail-center">
                 <font size="4">
                     <p>Trending Tweets</p>
                 </font>
             </div>
        {% for t,u in tweets,urls %}
        {{ t }}{{ u }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

But when I run the server I got the following error:

```html
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Could not parse the remainder: ',urls' from 'tweets,urls'
```

Please help me how can I iterate throw two list?

Comment: By using a `zip`.

Comment: could you please write it down correct loop syntax. I tried but fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `zip` in the view, to make an iterator that iterates over the lists concurrently:

```
def twitter_trend(request):
    tweets, urls = main()
    context = {
        'tweets_urls': zip(tweets, urls),
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, "feed/trends.html", context)
```

and in the template, we can then iterate over the `tweets_url`:

```
{% extends 'feed/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="thumbnail-center">
                 <font size="4">
                     <p>Trending Tweets</p>
                 </font>
             </div>
        {% for t, u in tweets_urls %}
        {{ t }}{{ u }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

A zip takes two or more streams, and produces tuples of these streams. So for example:

```
>>> list(zip([1, 4, 2, 5], "ABCD"))
[(1, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (5, 'D')]
```

We thus make tuples where the left item is a `tweets` element, and the right an `urls` element.

Note that you have to make sure that the order of `tweets` and `urls` "*matches*": that the *i*-th `tweets` element is "related" to the *i*-th `urls` element. `zip(..)` simply takes the order of the two iterables, it does not have any "*magic*" to check if it makes sense to link the elements.

Comment: This is what i want to achieve and you helped me in this http://trendinganalytica.com/twitter/

Comment: Probably you want to replace `{{ t }}{{ u }}` with `<a href="{{ u }}">{{ t }}</a>` or something similar.